# Adolescent basketball strength training

Tags: basketball, training, performance

I am a 13-year-old boy who would like to improve his basketball performance using strength training. I am 5' 5" and 110 lbs. What are some exercises or workouts I can do safely to improve my biceps, triceps, quads, calves, or other muscles used in basketball?

Comment: You should also ask this on the [fitness site](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @rrirower No, this should be asked *only* on Physical Fitness; Stack Exchange explicitly discourages cross-posting the same question to more than one site.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using some body weight exercises like:

- push-ups - will develop different upper body muscles depending on width/direction of your hands on the floor
- squats - will develop thigh/glutes strength for jumping
- calf raises - will develop your calf muscles
- Playdoh - Might seem like an odd suggestion but manipulating playdoh will help build wrist/forearm strength

In addition to strength training, you should also look at plyometrics for improving quickness. Exercises like box/squat jumps will help utilising the strength you have developed.